# How to find correcet ticker for pandas web reades? (google)

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to get data on an index from google finance.

The ticker is: INDEXDJX:DJSPHM or just DJSPHM.

I am using this code, and have tried variious combinations of the tickers, but nothing work. The data is readily available on their website. So that is not the issue. If I write another ticker, fx google, then data is fetched perfectly.

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)
f = web.DataReader("F", 'INDEXDJX:DJSPHM', start, end)
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix: `f = web.DataReader('DJSPHM', "yahoo", start, end)`

You have 2 problems

1. The argument order is incorrect (ticker is first, data_source is second).  The original posted code looks for ticker "F" on source "INDEXDJX:DJSPHM".  You say "If I write another ticker, fx google, then data is fetched perfectly.", however what you are getting is ticker F from google.  At least on Pandas master, it does not complain if the source is not one of the working sources ("google", "yahoo", "fred", "famafrench"), it just returns nothing.
   Your last line should be:

   `f = web.DataReader("INDEXDJX:DJSPHM", "google", start, end)`
2. Google does in fact has a problem retrieving the dates for DJSPHM.  Here's the error you'll get:

   `IOError: after 3 tries, Google did not return a 200 for url 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDJX%3ADJSPHM&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&output=csv'`

   however Yahoo works fine. `f = web.DataReader('DJSPHM', "yahoo", start, end)`